# Data Encryption static encrypt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

My hexidigit is changing on day by day basis. How can I change it back to static

**Code**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host="######", user="##", password="######", database="#######")
query = """SELECT * from table """
df = pd.read_sql(query, myconn) #getting hexidigit back from the SQL server after dumping the ecrypted data into the database

def resize_length(string):
    #resizes the String to a size divisible by 16 (needed for this Cipher)
    return string.rjust((len(string) // 16 + 1) * 16)

def encrypt(url, cipher):
    # Converts the string to bytes and encodes them with your Cipher
    cipherstring = cipher.encrypt(resize_length(url).encode())
    cipherstring = "".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in cipherstring)
    return cipherstring

def decrypt(text, cipher):
    # Converts the string to bytes and decodes them with your Cipher
    text = bytes.fromhex(text)
    original_url = cipher.decrypt(text).decode().lstrip()
    return original_url

# It is important to use 2 ciphers with the same information, else the system breaks
# Define the Cipher with your data (Encryption Key and IV)
cipher1 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
cipher2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
message = df['values'][4]
eypt = encrypt(message, cipher1)
print(decrypt(eypt, cipher2))
```

I'm able to decrypt the string after calling from database but on the next day the encrypted string changes which fails my code. How can I freeze this? Keeping a constant string everyday?

Comment: nothing here updates your database at all ... so not sure how you expect someone to tell you how to not update the database in this code ...

Comment: How can we possibly know anything about your database?

Comment: @FrankYellin problem is how to keep the encrypted key static. From database I am getting my input which is stored as a hexi string. To simplify, I'm converting my password to hexi format and storing it into the database. Later on, after getting the string back from the database I'm feeding it to the decrypt(). Problem here is the hexi string is changing each and everyday. Hence, the code fails. Is there any way to make it static?

Comment: @JoranBeasley database is only used to store the string. I'm not applying any sort of function or anything to the string. Entire encryption and decryption takes place using python. Problem is I'm getting different encrypted string each and everyday. How can I make is static?

Comment: the same string will always decrypt with the same string ... so either the string in the database is changing or the key you are using to decrypt it is changing ... neither of those events are shown in this code

Comment: @JoranBeasley yeah. Actually i got the solution for that. After encoding the string, I am parsing b' from each encoded byte and dumping it into the database as a string. Later on using the function -> bytes(input, 'utf-8') , I'm able to convert the given input into byte format and decrypt the string. Thanks for the input and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution by encrypting the key using bytes()
Use the byte method to store the key in secured config file or database and encrypt the byte string to get the key. After that use any cipher method with suitable algorithm to encrypt the data and mask it.